# IntelliJ Idea Slack user channel

Tags: intellij-idea, slack

Is there a Slack user group / community dedicated to everything IntelliJ Idea such as keyboard shortcuts, plugins, support inquires, feature discussions, etc and if so what is its URL?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not slack, but we have a new Discord server for JetBrains full of users and JetBrains staff. It has channels for all JetBrains products inclduing IntelliJ IDEA. https://discord.gg/ysd6M4r